# VB.NET String split in advance (C# or VB.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

This is the text lines,that I want to split,data.txt (some text file)

```
AAEJEY CONSUMER COMPANY                    61469 HH13811 4796000501758   NILMA LIQUID BLUE                240 75ML         960.00  20131002
EVERGREEN MARKETING                        61485 PC21946 3014260818685   ORALB 7 BENEFITS T/BRUSH          12 EACH         120.00  20131002
HARISCHANDRA MILLS PLC                     61488 BV50201 4792083040122   HARISCHANDRA COFFEE               40 50GR        4000.00  20131002
```

Between 'COMPANY' and '61469' space length may be vary line to line.
**I want to split that line as following.**

> AAEJEY CONSUMER COMPANY
>
> 61469
>
> HH13811
>
> 4796000501758
>
> NILMA LIQUID BLUE
>
> 240
>
> 75ML
>
> 960.00
>
> 20131002

This is my code,it split all with space,but i cannot get the Company Name (AAEJEY CONSUMER COMPANY) as a single name or Item Name (NILMA LIQUID BLUE) as a single name.

```
Dim myArray() As String, delimiter As Char = " "
        Dim strBuild As String = ""
        Dim b As Boolean = False
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Try
            Using sr As New StreamReader(fileName)
                Dim line As String
                While Not sr.EndOfStream
                    line = sr.ReadLine()
                    Console.WriteLine(line)
                    myArray = line.Split(delimiter)
                    Dim order As New OrdData()
                    For index As Integer = 0 To myArray.Length - 1
                        If myArray(index) = "" Then
                            i = index
                            myArray.Skip(1)                                
                        Else                               
                            strBuild += myArray(index) + " "
                            Console.WriteLine(strBuild)
                        End If

                    Next
                End While
            End Using
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:")
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: Is the data always formatted so consistently? If so you may want to grab trimmed sub strings for each column

Comment: Yes.data always formatted consistently.but some time name have 3 part or 4 part or some time 2 parts
ex : DANISHT IMPEX or DANISHT IMPEX LIMITED as company name

Comment: If space is your delimiter, then you necessarily cannot have parts of your document that use spaces, unless those parts are "escaped" (perhaps by being in quotes). But it does indeed look like you have fixed column widths, so go with the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this handy functional approach.

First define a function to recursively split a line:

```
Dim f As Func(Of String, IEnumerable(Of Integer), IEnumerable(Of String)) = Nothing
f = Function(t, ns)
    If ns.Any() Then
        Dim n = ns.First()
        Dim i = System.Math.Min(n, t.Length)
        Dim t0 = t.Substring(0, i)
        Dim t1 = t.Substring(i)
        Return New List(Of String) From { t0.Trim() }.Concat(f(t1, ns.Skip(1)))
    Else
        Return New List(Of String) From { t.Trim() }
    End If
End Function
```

Then define your splits like this:

```
Dim splits = { 43, 6, 8, 16, 31, 6, 10, 11 }
```

Now you can run it like this:

```
Dim fields = f(line, splits).ToArray()
```

Given your first line of data I got this result:

[image: result]

Comment: Your are correct but some time integer length may vary...that's the issue on this. Any way this is good.

Comment: @Elshan - I know the length of the strings vary, but do the number of characters (including the spaces) between the field vary?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a fixed length file format, so you should actually go by the number of characters, e.g.

```
line = sr.ReadLine()
var name = line.Substring(0, 43).Trim();
var number = line.Substring(44, 5).Trim();
```

Your file doesn't have any delimiter. You cannot use spaces as spaces are part of the items (the first column).

Comment: `strBuild = line.Substring(0, 42).Trim()`

Comment: But the start of the next number (not sure what it is) is always in the same position?

Comment: If the company name "is different sometimes" could you please show an example?

Comment: DANISHT IMPEX or DANISHT IMPEX LIMITED 
this two names have 2 and 3 parts as a company name

Comment: Yes but it's still within the first 43 characters (or whatever the count is). If you use the code below (you may need to tweak the numbers), it will be treated as one.

Comment: @Szymon yes you are correct.second split contain integer value,we cannot get that integer value length directly. ex :99999 length 5,but next time it will increase as 100000.then our Sub string will fail

Comment: Then take it starting one character to the left. The point is, if you don't have any separators, you must rely on **fixed** widths of each column and you cannot change those widths. You need to decide what is the maximum number you can get and provide enough space for it.

Comment: @Elshan it does look like your data is in fixed length fields you just need to determine what the field lengths are.

Comment: @Szymon Your way to resolve problem  is nice.I think first time we sub-string and then we can split in "space" then again sub-string Item Code again. because char value has actual length other than integers.i'll try that.

Comment: @MarkHall yes mark the thing is integer value cant get the actual length.it me vary with next number sequence.But it's ok to characters(var chars ex:Company name [AAEJEY CONSUMER COMPANY] or item code[NILMA LIQUID BLUE])

Comment: You can always pad it with spaces when saving, e.g. `string x = (100).ToString().PadLeft(5);`. There's also `PadRight` method.

Comment: @Elshan what I am saying is that it does have a fixed starting spot, you just have to determine what is the maximum length of the First field. It probably will take you looking at the contents of a few files to see what the lengths are.  Or look at the settings of the software that is creating the file

Comment: @MarkHall First field maximum length is 42

Comment: @Elshan then your second has a maximum length of 6, something like this should work `line.Substring(43, 6).Trim()`